# Propensity score to match on exposure thats not a treatment

Tags: regression, propensity-scores

I have two questions on this subject:

(1) The literature on propensity score (PS) consistently discusses the ability of PS to balance groups with different treatments. Does PS allow for balancing on exposures other than treatment, such as being a case (ex have suffered a myocardial infarction) vs control. Because I have a data set with cases and controls, which are not comparable at baseline, so I'm thinking about using PS to balance the groups.

(2) If it can be done, what PS measure (weight, distance, subclass etc) should I use to compare the groups. I want to compare these groups for various categorical and continuous variables, to see if they differ. Any specific tests to use? Use regression?

I'd be grateful for some advice on this.

Comment: PS (best done using covariate adjustment on regression splines of logit PS) is done to correct for measured potential confounders when assessing the association between an exposure (often a treatment) and $Y$.  It is only logical to develop a PS model to predict the exposure (treatment) of interest.  It would help if you were to state the goal of the modeling exercise, along with the sample size and distribution of $Y$ and total number of potential confounders.  Depending on the effective sample size and dimensionality of the problem you may not need PS at all.

Comment: Thanks Prof Harrell. The data set consists of 100 controls and 200 cases. The cases have a family history of myocardial infarction, the controls have not. The goal is to see whether these groups differ for, e.g, degree of dyslipidaemia, blood pressure. I have 30 relevant variables (biomarkers, anthropometric measures etc). Comparing the two groups directly via typical significance tests won't be satisfactory due differences at baseline. I reasoned that I'd use a PS matching package to match on age, sex and BMI to get subclasses based on PS, and then use these to analyze comparable groups...

Comment: You are implying in your last sentence that you will be deleting observations.  This is not necessarily a scientific approach to the problem.  But more to the point, what is your real hypothesis/goal?  You already know from the literature how many of your variables relate to myocardial infarction.  History of MI needs to be further defined to take age/time into account.

Comment: The hypothesis is to examine heredity: individuals who are relatives to persons who suffered an MI, do they have more dyslipidaemia as compared to healthy controls? Do they have higher blood pressure? I thought that using subclasses would avoid the problem of discarding cases/controls. Initially, I thought I'd go for regression; having cholesterol as dependent variable, and case/control status and independent, with weighting for PS weights or something similar. Then I thought that perhaps I could compare groups without regression, instead weighting for the PS? You can probably tell I'm lost...

Comment: Subclasses will result in residual confounding due to binning continuous variables.  Weighting on PS will increase variance.  Covariate adjustment, after checking for non-overlap PS regions, is likely to work well.  Using the terms "case" and "control" confuses the issues to me and implies retrospective sampling.  Try to state the hypothesis as a model, e.g. identify a parameter with family history and ask whether median total cholesterol or mean log chol. is associated with fam hx adjusting for all  covariates measured concurrently with cholesterol (a slightly strange H0).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. When You write "covariate adjustment, after checking for non-overlap PS regions", do You mean that I should use regression and adjust for PS as a covariate? (I'm a bit confused..)

Comment: Yes.  If you don't have a problem with non-overlap, a regression spline in the logit of PS is a very flexible bias-removing high-precision approach.  We occasionally assume linearity in logit(PS) but the regression spline does away with the need for that assumption while solving the problem of residual confounding.

Comment: Many many thanks prof Harrell! Appreciate Your time.

Comment: For those who are also interested in this question, I found this article: http://www.nejm.org/doi/pdf/10.1056/NEJMoa1311889

Which performs such an analysis.